# Induction over a range of values

Tags: number-theory, induction, continued-fractions

In the induction proof below where $[a_0; a_1,\ldots, a_h]$ is a continued fraction, could someone please clarify which induction method is being used here? Is it:

1. an induction over $i$ and $h$ i.e. show for each $h\in \mathbb{N}_0$ that it the result holds for all $-1\leqslant i \leqslant h$.
2. an induction only over $i$. Where $h$ is just a given value in $\mathbb{N}_0$

[image]

I initially assumed it was the first option but I struggled a lot and wasn’t able to do the ‘straightforward’ induction. If it is the second option then why for the base step is the result proven for $i=-1$ and $i=0$ and not just for one value?

Comment: You use the induction hypothesis for $p_{i-1}$ and $ p _{i-2}$ to conclude that it is true for $p_i$. So, it's stronger than your second option, essentially your first option (though doesn't need to be that strong). They did 2 base cases of $ i = -1, i = 0 $, because they need the previous 2 induction steps to hold.

Comment: A lecturer thought I it may be option 2 but I’ve never seen induction between a range of values before.

Comment: You can induct on $\mathbb{N}$, and then restrict it to any range that you want. E.g. sometimes people start with $n > 3$, or use the result for even/odd $n$, etc.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to prove the formula for the $d_i$‘s. I just mentioned the recursive formula for the $p_i,q_i$ for better background information

Comment: I think you could consider this [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) (like option 2), where the induction hypothesis holds for all values up to $h$, or you could consider it regular induction (like option 1), with the proposition $P(h)$ being that the equation holds for $h$ and $h-1$

Comment: yea, that was a typo. i meant it for $d_i$. Can you show your induction proof, and explain where it is that you're stuck?

Comment: Yes. I’ll attach it at the bottom of my question now.

Comment: A similar situation occurs with proofs by induction regarding Fibonacci numbers, since each depends on the previous *two* values

Comment: So do you think we definitely have to do induction over $h$ and not just over $i$? The book is lying about being straightforward.

Comment: So @CalvinLin in your first comment you mean prove by induction given $h\in \mathbb{N}_0$ arbitrary (I.e. do not induct over $h$), and the induction hypothesis is: for $0\leqslant i\leqslant h$, the $d_i$ statement holds for $i-1,i-2$ and the inductive step is to show that it holds for $i$?

Comment: I also made a typo.:  strong induction is your option 1 and regular induction is 2

Comment: "but I’ve never seen induction between a range of values before. "  There's no reason it wouldn't work.  If there's a natural ceiling you can do induction from a base case up as for as you set goes. And stop... to be continued...

Comment: Thought experiment.  Suppose you know that if humans exist in a year babies will be born that year; and if babies are born some will survive to be a year old unless a meteor hits and they all die; a meteor will hit in 2030 and the world will end but no other meteor has or will hit the planet at any other time; a human being was sighted in France in the year 961AD. Prove: Humans exist on the planet for the years $961$ through $2030$. You prove it by induction. But it stops at $2030$.

Comment: Thank you for your analogy. I proved it alone just there using the induction hypothesis in my comment to @CalvinLin. If that induction hypothesis is ok then I managed to do it. Thanks everyone for your thoughts.

Comment: How is showing the statement is true for $i=-1$ and $i=0$ sufficient when the $d_i, p_i, q_i$ are only represented by the recursive formula when $i\geq 1$? Are these just separate cases and for a base step I must show it is true for $i=1$ and $i=2$?

Comment: I think if I define $d_{-2}=1$ then I can then say the recursive for works for $i\geq 0$ instead and thus $i=0,1$ is enough for a base step, both of which I know how to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2:  It's definitely option 2.

This is induction over $i$ for a fixed $h$.

Of course $h$ could be any value as there is nothing it the proof that requires any specific qualities of $h$ (other than $h\in \mathbb N_0$).

Don't be confused in that this is a proof by induction on one variable, $i$, but a proof by generality on another, $h$.  Don't forget a "proof by generality"--- to prove something is true for all values of a set $G$, which can be $\mathbb N_0$ or any other set, by arbitrarily picking a value, $w\in G$, and showing it is true for $w$, therefore it is true for all elements in $G$ because ... there was nothing special about $w$--- is still valid.

so the statement is: For any $h\in \mathbb N_0$ and for an $i: 1\le i \le h$ then .... something.

And the proof goes like:

- Fix an arbitrary $h_0 \in \mathbb N_0$ (the subscript $_0$ is my idea; the author didn't think it was necessary-- it wasn't but it illustrates my point).
- Prove via induction on $i$ that the statement is true for all $-1 \le i \le h_0$.
- Then conclude that because $h_0$ was arbitrary, it must be true for all $h \in \mathbb N_0$.

Comment: I should mention I made up the term "proof by generality".  It's usually supposed to be self evident.  "Prove blah is true for all blech.  Let $x$ be blech ... a bunch of stuff to prove $x$ is blah... end of proof".  Yes, you can state that.  You want to assume it is true for $i-1, i-2$ in order to prove it is true for $i$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the induction step here, you need to assume the induction hypothesis is true for the previous two values of $i$, since $d_i$ depends on $d_{i-1}$ and $d_{i-2}$.

I think you could view this either as [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) -- like your option (1), where the induction hypothesis is that the statement holds for all values from $-1$ to $i$ -- or you could view it as regular induction (like your option (2)), where the proposition $P(i)$ is that it holds for $i$ and $i-1$, and that's why you would need to prove the base step for two values.

Comment: I proved it using using the regular induction for 2 previous values. Thank you

Comment: I think I may have encountered a problem. How is showing the statement is true for $i=-1$ and $i=0$ sufficient when the $d_i, p_i, q_i$ are only represented by the recursive formula when $i\geq 1$? Are these just separate cases and for a base step I must show it is true for $i=1$ and $i=2$?